# Is order guaranteed when collecting reactions in a discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Let's say a bot is collecting reactions to a certain message to represent registering in an event

[image: Embed Representation Example]

To make sure no races happen I have already locked the underlying data structure behind a mutex but this doesn't really give the notion of priority since person #33 can go in before #32 if it was the one to acquire the lock after it was released once person #31 releases his lock

```js
const rCollector = msg.createReactionCollector(filterEventReaction);
rCollector.lock = new Mutex();

rCollector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
    const role = reaction.emoji.name;
    const release = await rCollector.lock.acquire();
    try {
       if(role === "cancel") { unregisterFromEvent(user, event); return; }
       registerInEvent(user, event, role);
    } finally { release(); }
});
```

This atleast make sure no 2 users edit at the same time which works well however I'd like to have them processed in order of reacting but I still have the same concerns about the races happening

1. Does Discord.JS "collect" events guarantee order when called? As in will they be called by order of reactions
2. Assuming events are triggered in order will that even guarantee they'll be processed in order?
3. If I introduce a queue that users are put in when they react will that solve it?
4. What even guarantees they'll be put in order? even locking it introduces the same the same dilemma above

Thanks for reading. There's probably an easy solution I'm not aware of and I'm overthinking it but as always applications of this nature aren't exactly easy to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#consistency

[image: Snippet]

So it's safe to say it's not guaranteed although not borked 100% of the time. It's an interesting read of BASE vs the usual ACID approach.